# generating css file from new sass format (scss) with sinatra and haml

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml, sass

I am writing a sinatra app with haml and sass. When I try to link in the stylesheet with a scss extension located in my views folder I get the following error: NoMethodError at /nav.css undefined method `scss'

Here is my get method

```
get '/nav.css' do 
    content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
    scss :nav
end
```

I have only gotten this to work when I switch to the older sass syntax. I also have to change the nav.scss to nav.sass and the get method to sass :nav

I have also tried just having sass :nav with nav.scss and sass :nav with nav.sass but still scss syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from Sinatra [README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro)

```
## You'll need to require haml or sass in your app
require 'sass'

get '/stylesheet.css' do
  scss :stylesheet
end
```

Are you required the sass gem?

What version of Sinatra you use. Support for `scss` was added in 2010.09.01 (same day version was increased from 1.0 to 1.1), perhaps you need and update.

Comment: I am requiring the haml gem. I also tried requiring just sass and both sass and haml but not none of them worked. I have no trouble rendering haml views or the old sass syntax stylesheets but the new ones are a problem.

Comment: I installed sinatra during the first week of Oct. but for some reason gem install sinatra fixed the problem

Comment: Officially the Sinatra 1.1.0 was released 3 days ago, so before `gem install` installed Sinatra 1.0, meanwhile  was some pre `gem install sinatra --pre`. Anyway glad you succeed :).

Answer (score 13):

I don't use the above code from the README, just put the following in your app.rb file after updating your gem.

```
get '/stylesheets/:name.css' do
 content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
 scss(:"stylesheets/#{params[:name]}")
end
```

Restart your server and you're all set. Happy Scssing.