# Does Sinatra come with sass out the box?

Tags: sass, sinatra

I have never worked with Sinatra (but I have worked with Rails) and am confused as to if it comes with Sass out-the-box, this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029916/generating-css-file-from-new-sass-format-scss-with-sinatra-and-haml) gives me the impression that as of version 1.1 it does, however all the other things (tutorials, articles, etc) gives me the impression a gem needs to be installed and required. Looking at the [docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) it seems that it may be out-the-box indeed. Yet I am not clear how to implement it, it says:

```
SCSS Templates

Dependency  sass
File Extension  .scss
Example scss :stylesheet, :style => :expanded
```

and in my code I have put `require 'sass'` at the top of my `config.ru` and 
`scss :stylesheet, :style => :expanded`

to look like this:

```
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/param"
require "json"
require 'sass'

set :raise_sinatra_param_exceptions, true

disable :show_exceptions
disable :raise_errors

scss :stylesheet, :style => :expanded

helpers do
   //....stuff
end
```

However it does not seem to be working. Does Sass actually come out-the-box? And if so, how to I set it up? Or do I need to install a gem as I would in Rails?

UPDATE: 
Here is my current file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The call to the `scss` method needs to be inside a route, not at the top level like you have here. You need something like this:

```ruby
get '/style'
  scss :stylesheet
end
```

Then in your other templates you would have something like this (this example is using Haml):

```haml
!!!
%title Hello
%link{:rel => 'stylesheet', :href => url('style')}
```

Sinatra includes methods for rendering Scss and Sass, but don’t install the gem or require anything automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your response! For clarification - are you just noting that Sinatra doesn't install the gem automatically (but it should indeed be installed)? Or are you saying "don't install the gem" (as in I should NOT install the gem at all)? Also I am not familiar with using Haml, I am just using a regular index.html file, should the link in the head just look like `<link href="assets/sass/style.scss" rel="stylesheet">` ?

Comment: I have removed the `scss :stylesheet, :style => :expanded` from my file and added `get 'sass/style.scss' do
  scss :stylesheet
end` but it is not working. The route should be pointing sinatra to where my .scss is located right?

Comment: @HolyMoly yes, you need to install the gem if you want to use Sass/Scss. The Haml line that starts `%link...` will generate pretty much the same as your `link` HTML element, so that’s correct too.

Comment: I should point out that this is using Scss in a slightly different way than you may be used to in Rails. This code will process your `.scss` file and convert it to CSS _on every request_. Rails is a bit more sophisticated, and will convert the code dynamically like this in developent, but in production will create a static file that will be served instead of reprocessing each time. If you want a more Rails like way of handling Scss with Sinatra you could look at something like [sprockets](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/asset_management/sprockets).

Comment: When you do `scss :stylesheet`, Sinatra will expect a file `stylesheet.scss` in your `views` directory. So if it is in an `assets` directory it won’t work. The `href` in the HTML should match the route in `get`, and the arg passed to `scss` should match the file location under `views`.

Comment: gotcha. And thank you so much for your help! I don't have a views directory, my html file (my view)  is in the public folder. This will be the only page I am creating.... will it be necessary to create a views folder, or can the code be modified to reflect it's current location? If not should I create a folder called views and move my style.scss file into it along with my index.html, or will it just be enough to move my stayle.scss into it and change the paths as needed?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a snapshot of my file structure. I should note that I did not create this app, it belongs to someone else (an am therefore cautious about heavily changing it's structure unless necessary). As I mentioned, I have never used sinatra - and this file structure looks quite different than what I am seeing in tutorials (no view folder) - is this just another way to do it if you only have one view? And do you NEED to have the more traditional structure to implement sass?